# Alpine locales for docker image (php gettext)

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to use php **gettext()** with docker image **php:7.2-fpm-alpine3.7**

my Dockerfile is

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine3.7

RUN apk add --update --no-cache icu-dev gettext gettext-dev \
           && docker-php-ext-install intl gettext
```

but it does not translate.
I found that extensions are ok, and trouble with locales. Alpine does not support locales properly.

Is there any way to use `locales` (and php `gettext()`) with alpine docker image?

Comment: hey Andrei did you ever get around that issue? I'm having the same problem right now

Comment: @RaulG No, I didn't. For now I choose debian slim instead of alpine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add \
    icu-dev \
    gettext \
    gettext-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gettext \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    intl \
    gettext
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!